# remove special characters in java

Tags: java

My excel cell has value as:

> My – Non-Medical Helper

Using poi library I am reading excel(xls) file and get this value as string, but output come as

> My â€“ Non-Medical Helper

how to replace such character to get expected value.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is Charsets.  You may want to make sure that you're decoding the spreadsheet with the right Charset, and that may make your problem "just go away."

Answer (score 0):

you could just use a regex to filter out the non-printing character and replace it with a '-'. [check this out](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=80) - it's got lots of examples i think you'll find useful.